# AR model lattice implementation

Tags: signal-processing, matlab, voice

I'm trying to go through the procedure of Speech Synthesis via **AR model**, or **LPC synthesis**, **IIR all-pole** filter model, what ever you call it.

The main idea is to get the ***auto-correlation(AR) coefficient*** and ***estimate error***, then use the AR coefficients to filter the estimated error, we can get the reconstructed signal.

```
**MATLAB CODE**

data = [1 2 1 3 5 1 2 5];
% auto correlation coefficients
a = lpc(data, 4);

% estimated signal
est = filter([0 -a(2:end)],1,data);
% estimated error
e = data - est;
% reconstructed signal
rec = filter(1,a,e);
```

You will see that rec == data exactly.

**Now comes my question.**

I'm trying to convert the model into Latices implementation. After looking up the Matlab reference, it turned out that I should use

```
tf2latc
```

to convert the transfer function into lattice implementation and

```
latcfilt
```

to use the lattice to filter the data.

Simply repeating the procedure above just doesn't work.

So I'm looking for help in the following aspects:

1) Example on using the tr2latc and latcfilt function to perform a complete procedure of building the filter.
2) Example on using a lattice implementation to perform a voice reconstruction.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, finally I got the answer.

From a transfer function, we can get the lattice implementation coefficients. Then filter it with latcfilt.

```
a = [1 3 1 4 4];
[k v] = tf2latc(1,a)
x = [1 2 1 3 4 1 5];
filter(1,a,x)
latcfilt(k,v,x)
```

Then you can see that the two filter gives the same result.